# AngularDart throws error while implementing firebase login

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, angular-dart, dart-html

I am trying to implement firebase google login in my AngularDart project but while implementing angular dart throws an error. I have rechecked for the `*ngIf`typo but unable to find the needful required.

Kindly help me with this thank you.

```
Error running TemplateGenerator for 
my_app|lib/views/layout_component/layout_component.dart.
Error: Template parse errors:
line 32, column 35 of LayoutComponent: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind to 
'ngIf' since it isn't a known native property or known directive. Please fix 
typo or add to directives list.
*ngIf="fbService.user == null"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 32, column 17 of LayoutComponent: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Property 
binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template
<div id="sign-in" *ngIf="fbService.user == null" class="horiz">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 37, column 36 of LayoutComponent: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind to 
'ngIf' since it isn't a known native property or known directive. Please fix 
typo or add to directives list.
*ngIf="fbService.user != null"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 37, column 17 of LayoutComponent: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Property 
binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template
<div id="sign-out" *ngIf="fbService.user != null" class="horiz">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:your_next_startup/views/layout_component/layout_component.dart';
import 'package:your_next_startup/services/firebase_service.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [
    materialDirectives,
    LayoutComponent,
  ],
  providers: const [
    materialProviders,
    FirebaseService,
  ],
)
class AppComponent {
  final FirebaseService fbService;

  AppComponent(FirebaseService this.fbService);

}
```

layout_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:m_app/services/firebase_service.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'app-layout',
  styleUrls: const [
        'layout_component.css',
  ],
  templateUrl: 'layout_component.html',
  directives: const [
    materialDirectives,
  ],
  providers: const [
    FirebaseService,
  ],
)
class LayoutComponent {
  final FirebaseService fbService;
  LayoutComponent(FirebaseService this.fbService);
}
```

layout_component.html

```
<div class="horiz">
            <div id="sign-in" *ngIf="fbService.user == null" class="horiz">
                <div id="google-icon" class="icon"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" (click)="fbService.signIn()">Google Sign In</button>
            </div>

            <div id="sign-out" *ngIf="fbService.user != null" class="horiz">
                <img class="icon" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">
                <div id="user-name">{{fbService.user?.displayName}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" (click)="fbService.signOut()">Sign Out</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be related to firebase.

```
@Component(
  selector: 'app-layout',
  styleUrls: const [
        'layout_component.css',
  ],
  templateUrl: 'layout_component.html',
  directives: const [
    materialDirectives,
    NgIf,              // one of these two
    COMMON_DIRECTIVES, // this one includes NgIf, NgFor, NgSwitchCase, ...  
  ],
  providers: const [
    FirebaseService,
  ],
)
class LayoutComponent {
  final FirebaseService fbService;
  LayoutComponent(FirebaseService this.fbService);
}
```

In Angular 3 and earlier directives could be registered in `pubspec.yaml` for the whole application, this isn't supported anymore and all used directives need to be registered in the components annotation where they are used.